# Bounty expiration time mismatch between page and message/email

Tags: bug

The bounty that I posted on this question:

[Handling XBox 360 Controller Connections in LibGDX after Game has Started](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/67604/handling-xbox-360-controller-connections-in-libgdx-after-game-has-started)

...does not expire for another ~50 minutes (at time of writing), according to the page.  But at approximately 60 minutes remaining, I received an email and inbox message saying that the 24 hour grace period had begun.  So, there seems to be an hour mismatch between the two.

I reloaded the page several times, but the count of remaining minutes stays.  I'm at (UTC-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada) in windows7, btw.

[image]